# auto typography class in codeigniter not working

Tags: codeigniter, class, line-breaks

If a string is thus:

```
$str = "This is a\n\nstring!"
```

And I load the typography class in Codeigniter, and use it like this:

```
<?=auto_typography($str)?>
```

Should the HTML output not be:

```
<p>This is a</p>
<p>string!</p>
```

Why do I keep getting:

```
<p>This is a\n\nstring!</p>
```

How do I achieve what I want? Thanks!

Controller:

```
public function show($strId)
{
    $this->load->helper('segment3');
    $this->load->helper('typography');
    $this->load->model('segment3/Default_model');
    $data['head'] = $this->Default_model->segment3();
    $data['segment3'] = $this->Default_model->segment3();
    $this->load->view('head_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('header_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('segment3/__mainContent/default_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer_view', $data);
}
```

View:

```
<?php if (isset($segment3)):?>
    <?php foreach ($segment3 as $row):?>
        <h1><?=$row->title?></h1>
        <img src="/images/<?=$row->strId?>.jpg" class="scale-with-grid">
        <?=auto_typography($row->__mainContent)?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

$row->__mainContent is pulled from a database...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you enabled the helper in the controller?

If not, this needs to placed in your controller.

> $this->load->helper('typography');
>
> http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/typography_helper.html

If you did that correctly then the second thing I would look for is to make sure that you are loading the view correctly.

> $this->load->view('pathto/your/view');

If both of those are correct, then we are going to need more info to help you out. The code in your view and the controller would help alot.